# Highest Points to finish Runner-Up in Champions League Group? Lowest points to win Champions League Group?

Tags: football, trivia, champions-league

Theoretically, you could finish second even with 15 points. And win the group with just 5 points. But, in reality what are the records?
Is it Arsenal (with 13 points) this season and Monaco (with 11 points) this season?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Most points achieved in the group stage, not winning the group (2nd): Manchester City, 15, [2013-2014](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2013%E2%80%9314_UEFA_Champions_League_group_stage#Group_D).

Most points achieved in the group stage, yet knocked out (3rd): Napoli, 12, [2013-2014](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2013%E2%80%9314_UEFA_Champions_League_group_stage#Group_F).

Fewest points achieved in the first group stage, yet won the group: Juventus, 8, [1998-1999](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1998%E2%80%9399_UEFA_Champions_League_group_stage#Group_B) and Milan, 8, [1993-1994](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1993%E2%80%9394_UEFA_Champions_League_group_stage#Group_B).‡

Fewest points achieved in the second group stage: Valencia, 9, [2002-2003](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2002%E2%80%9303_UEFA_Champions_League_second_group_stage#Group_B) and Barcelona, [2001-2002](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2001%E2%80%9302_UEFA_Champions_League_second_group_stage#Group_B).

Fewest points achieved in the group stage, yet advanced: Milan, 5, [1994-1995](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1994%E2%80%9395_UEFA_Champions_League_group_stage#Group_D).‡

‡ *Prior to [1995-1996](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1995%E2%80%9396_UEFA_Champions_League) season two points were awarded for a win instead of three.*

[Source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/European_Cup_and_UEFA_Champions_League_records_and_statistics#Most_points_achieved.2C_yet_knocked_out)

Comment: Valencia and Barcelona, which you mention as teams to win a group in second group stage with fewest points, actually had 9 points, not 8.

Comment: I think it's essential to mention that prior to 1995/96 UEFA Champions League season **two points** were awarded **for a win** instead of three. So, keeping that in mind, Milan would accumulate 10 points in 1993/94 and 8 points in 1994/95.